# How to expose extra column data for each pairing on a many to many relationship?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a Cars table, a BodyPaints table, and a Cars_BodyPaints association table that defines what paint jobs are possible for various cars.  The association between Cars and BodyPaints is many to many.

I'd like to create an extra piece of data for each (Car, Paint) mapping to define the cost of a specific paint job on a specific car.  I have added an extra column to Cars_BodyPaints to record the price of each pairing, but when I update the model classes from the DB I don't see it exposed in any of the entity classes.  This leads me to believe that maybe my approach is wrong here.  I was excepting some method to be generated so I could execute code like:

```
Car civic = (from c in context.Cars  where c.Name == "Civic" select c).Single();
Paint red = (from p in civic.Paints  where p.Name == "Red"   select p).Single();

var price = civic.GetPrice(red);
```

Am I off base here?  How would you accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When modeling many-to-many relationships with attributes, you will need to model the relation as an entity itself.  You would create a new entity for the `Cars_BodyPaints` table and it would contain your extra price column as a property. This new intermediary entity must be traversed when considering the relation between `Cars` and `BodyPaints` and can also be directly queried.

`Cars <-- Cars_BodyPaints --> BodyPaints`

In this new model, your query would look more like:

```
(from bp in context.CarBodyPaints
where bp.Car.Name = "Civic" and bp.Paint.Name = "Red"
select bp.Price).Single()
```

Comment: @Michael thanks, I didn't realize I had to explicitly do it myself.  I created a new Entity Cars_BodyPaints as you suggested.  It has a CarId, PaintId, and Price.  The problem I have now is that the compiler complains that my entity does not have a key.  I don't think I can set either Id to be the key since values in that property will appear more than once across instances.  I need the key to be (CarId,PainId) like it is in the underlying DB table, but I am unsure of how to do that in the EF designer.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Dejas: Set both foreign keys as primary key - it is common practice when working with EF. Setting both fields as key is pretty easy - just go to property window and set `Entity key` to true.  If you don't specify primary key your entity will be readonly.

Comment: @Ladislav Thanks for the tip.  I went to the Cars_BodyPaints entity and I set both CarId and PaintId to be Entity keys.  Now I get the compilation error: `Error 3034: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 123, 133:Two entities with possibly different keys are mapped to the same row. Ensure these two mapping fragments map both ends of the AssociationSet to the corresponding columns.`

Comment: @Dejas: How did you create your mapping. If you have this correctly set up in DB and you simply recreate your model it should be ok.

Comment: @Ladislav 1.) Manually create Cars_BodyPaints entity. 2.) Right click on entity and select Table Mapping. 3.) [table] Cars_BodyPaints.CarId <-> [entity] CarsBodyPaints.CarId. 4.) [table] Cars_BodyPaints.PaintId <-> [entity] CarsBodyPaints.PaintId 5.) [table] Cars_BodyPaints.Price <-> [entity] Cars_BodyPaints.Price

Comment: @Dejas: The problem might be that the associations you had previously configured for `Cars --- BodyPaints` are conflicting with the new associations that should be `Cars <-- Cars_BodyPaints --> BodyPaints`.  For example, do you have an `EntitySet` association property on the `Cars` class that contains `BodyPaints` or `Cars_BodyPaints`?